# Why are my variables nil in the didMove delegate?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, delegates, initialization

In my `spriteKit` project I have a `delegate` that sets a `boolean` `variable` which is declared within the `class` scope. When the `didMove` delegate is run, the boolean is still `nil`. This despite that the `boolean` is `initialized` before `didMove` is triggered.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, MyProtocol {

    var isLandscape: Bool!

    func oriantationProtocol(isLandscape: Bool) {
        //initializing variable. this is triggered first
        self.isLandscape = isLandscape
    }...
```

then in `didMove`

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)

        print(" This right here is nil", self.isLandscape)

        if self.isLandscape {
            print("HERE")...
```

So, why is the `bool` nil in `didMove` when it is `initialized` before `didMove` is triggered?

Comment: How do you know `oriantationProtocol` is being called before `didMove`? Did you set debugger breakpoints to verify that?

Comment: I had a print in `oriantationProtocol` that triggered before `didMove`. Will try with the debugger as well. Thanks. If it doesn't work to set the book value using a protocol delegate pattern, how do I do it?

Comment: It should work. Be sure both functions are being called on the same instance of the scene though. I've seen people occasionally get confused and construct a new scene for the `didMove` when they previously had done some setup on a different instance of the scene, and then they wondered why their setup had vanished.

Comment: Your prints are lying to you.  Check to see if it is the same scene like @bg2b said.  Apple will create multiple scenes (and then destroy them) during the initialization process depending on what frameworks you use.